# Changing c++ compiler in visual studio 2017 professional

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need to change the compiler of microsoft in visual studio 2017 c++ professional to another one like gcc .. how can i do that?

Comment: Yes, you can... Please write your answers in the answer section so that they can be downvoted when they are factually incorrect, @Michael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following [the instructions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/).

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 supports several C++ compilers to suit a wide variety of codebases.  In addition to the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler that many of you are likely familiar with, Visual Studio 2017 also supports Clang, GCC, and other compilers when targeting certain platforms.

Comment: The user is asking for the steps to take to change the compiler toolchain. Both the link you have provided as well as the quote you have made from there in your answer do not actually specify "how to" -- click on this menu option, navigate to that setting, etc.